# Is it possible to have mysql unique index for specific column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the weird title, couldn't write it better...

[image]

Take a look at the image above.

In mysql, is it possible/feasible to have column UNIQUE based on user_id?

Let me rephrase this, is it possible to have order column values all unique only for specific user_id?

So that, if for user_id = 1 order = 1 and there cannot be another order = 1. But if user_id = 2 I can have order = 1 again?

Or is it better/faster to control this in php script that interfaces with mysql?

Comment: Is your table InnoDB or MyISAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking a couple of independent questions.

(1) Yes, you can have unique orders only for a customer.  In this case you need to create an unique index using both columns.

(2) Is it better/faster to control this in php script that interfaces with mysql? The first question has to do with data integrity not performance.  It will be faster to generate new word_id's if that is an auto-increment column because if it is not, your PHP code needs to query the database to find the largest value and add one.

If you want to have unique word_id per customer, you will need to generate those in your PHP code.  MySQL cannot generate new auto-increment values based on another column (because you are using InnoDB)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a compund index that enforces uniqueness on its compound values like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `myUniqueIndex` ON mytable (user_id, order)
```

Any attempt to insert a row with a duplicate compound value will return an error you can check for

Comment: Indeed your need to check on error 1062 in your application code to detected if your insert has triggerd an duplicate.. something like this in PHP    if(((int)mysqli_errno($link)) === 1062) { //handle duplicated here }    if you are using an framework most likly it throws an Exception what you need to try catch handle but you need to read the frameworks manual

Answer (score 0):

Create an unique composite key on 2 columns.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE KEY `someName` (user_id, `order`);
```